# Build error after updating Svelte: Package subpath './compiler.js' is not defined by "exports"

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json, svelte

### Problem

I was on *Svelte* version 3.0.0 and used `npm i svelte@latest` to update to the most recent version. Now I can't get the app to run, I always get this errror:

> [!] Error: Package subpath './compiler.js' is not defined by "exports" in /home/blub/coding/bla/node_modules/svelte/package.json
> Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './compiler.js' is not defined by "exports" in /home/blub/coding/bla/node_modules/svelte/package.json

### Failed Solutions

I also updated *rollup-plugin-svelte* to version 5.2.0, but that did not help. Are there any other dependencies I also have to update? Here is a list of my dependencies:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "rollup": "^2.44.0",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^1.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-node-resolve": "^5.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-svelte": "^5.2.3",
    "rollup-plugin-terser": "^4.0.4",
    "svelte": "^3.37.0",
    "svelte-preprocess-sass": "^0.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "sirv-cli": "^0.4.4"
  },
```

Comment: I guess this one is fix in the `v6.1.1` of `rollup-plugin-svelte`.

Comment: Yes, updating it fixed my issue. Thanks. Do you want to post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This issue is due to a breaking change of svelte `v3.29.5`. So if you want to use this version you will also need to update `rollup-plugin-svelte` to at least `v6.1.1`:

```sh
npm i -D rollup-plugin-svelte@6.1.1
# or with yarn
yarn add -D rollup-plugin-svelte@6.1.1
```

Comment: Here is the command to update `rollup-plugin-svelte` to at least `v6.1.1`. `npm i rollup-plugin-svelte@6.1.1`

Answer (score 2):

I had an old Svelte project and did not have time to update it all. I found downgrading Svelte to 3.29.4 fixed the issue.

```
npm i -D svelte@3.29.4
```